# SUM On Column With Group By SQL

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-function

I have following data:

```
+----------------+--------------+-----+
| StgDescription |      ID      | Amt |
+----------------+--------------+-----+
| A              | OA17         |  11 |
| A              | OA17         |  11 |
| A              | OA17         |  11 |
| A              | OA17         |  11 |
| B              | ZA47/ A      |  12 |
| B              | ZA47/ A      |  12 |
| B              | ZA47/ B      |  10 |
| B              | ZA47/ B      |  10 |
| B              | ZA48/ A      |  14 |
| B              | ZA48/ F      |  10 |
| B              | ZA48 /G      |  13 |
| B              | ZA48 /H      |  10 |
| B              | ZA48/ I      |  15 |
| B              | ZA48/ J      |  10 |
| B              | ZA48/ K      |  16 |
| B              | ZA48/ L      |  10 |
| c              | FA01LM100340 |  10 |
| c              | PA53 AE      |  10 |
+----------------+--------------+-----+
```

I want to generate report in following format. The amount should be sum for  ID for same StgDescription.

```
+----------------+-----+
| StgDescription | Amt |
+----------------+-----+
| a              |  11 |
| b              | 120 |
| c              |  20 |
+----------------+-----+
```

I've written following query to get this result:

```
  WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT 
     distinct
      s.StgDescription
     ,p.ID
        ,Amt

  FROM [DinDb].[dbo].[tblTvlTransaction] t
  JOIN tblstgmaster s on t.StgId=s.StgId
  JOIN tblProjDocSt p on t.TDocID=p.DocId
  JOIN  [PdasDb].[dbo].[tblIDmaster] f ON p.ID=f.ID
  where OptAuthoDateTime between '2015-07-27 00:00:00' and '2015-09-01 00:00:00')
  select  StgDescription,sum(AMT) from cte group by  StgDescription
```

Is there any other efficient alternative to do this?

Comment: So `a` shouldn't be `44`?

Comment: No it should not be 44. It should be 11. If there are multiple ID belongs to same stg, then they should be taken only once while calculating the sum.

Comment: Can you provide the logic for how to generate the final table? If you have the logical steps written down, people can easily guide you into arriving at your final answer, and it shows some work on your part instead of just posting a question asking us to solve it.

Comment: The most efficient way to do this would be to not retrieve the duplicate data at all, rather than retrieve it, then remove it using `DISTINCT`. Unfortunately I do not know your data structure well enough to suggest how to do this. What table do `Amt`, and `OptAuthoDateTime` come from?

Comment: Amt belongs to tblIDmaster and OptAuthDateTime belongs to tbltvltransaction

Comment: Just tossing in a `select distinct` is a band aid, not a true solution. There is also no compelling reason to use a CTE either.  You most probably need to do some grouping/summing before joining but without knowledge of the 4 tables unable to suggest specifics.

Comment: It is like I have to show monthly reports for each stage description with sum of amt. tblTvlTransaction table contains optauthdatetime. IDmaster contains ID and amt column.ProjectDocSt is join table for  IDMaster and tbltvltransaction.StgDescription is there in stgmaster table and stgid is being used as foreign key in tbltvltransaction.

Comment: @Priya no matter how hard you try to describe it, nothing works as well as "sample data" - which has to be "per table". What we particularly need to understand is any many-to-one relationships between the tables.

Answer (score 1):

First in cte remove duplicates, then `GROUP BY` like:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT StgDescription, ID, Amt 
   FROM your_tab
)
SELECT 
   StgDescription,
   Amt = SUM(Amt)
FROM cte
GROUP BY StgDescription;
```

OR:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT StgDescription, ID, Amt 
   FROM your_tab
   GROUP BY StgDescription, ID, Amt
)
SELECT 
   StgDescription,
   Amt = SUM(Amt)
FROM cte
GROUP BY StgDescription;
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope that you get the data from a query, not from a table. It would not be good to store data thus redundantly. And it would not be gould to name a column ID which is not the unique identifier for a row in a table.

Your problem with the data is that you have duplicates, which prevents you from getting the sum directly. So use DISTINCT to make your data unique first.

If this data is from a query then simply add `DISTINCT` after the `SELECT` keyword. If not, use a derived table (i.e. a subquery) where you select distinct records from the table.

```
select stgdescription, sum(amt)
from
(
  select distinct stgdescription, id, amt
  from mydata
) distinct_data
group by stgdescription;
```

You may want to replace `stgdescription` with `lower(stgdescription)`, though, if stgdescription can be 'A' or 'a' and you want to treat them the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep it as simple as possible, like this:

```
select StgDescription, sum(Amt) from
(
select distinct StgDescription, ID, Amt from tablename
) a
group by StgDescription
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your duplicates are coming from  `[tblTvlTransaction]`, therefore, I would remove this table as a `JOIN` and use `EXISTS` to just check a record is there. So essentially the only tables in the `FROM` clause are those you actually need data from:

```
SELECT  s.StgDescription, p.ID, s.Amt
FROM    tblstgmaster AS s
        INNER JOIN tblProjDocSt p on 
            t.TDocID = p.DocId
        INNER JOIN [PdasDb].[dbo].[tblIDmaster] AS f 
            ON p.ID = f.ID
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    [DinDb].[dbo].[tblTvlTransaction] AS t
            WHERE   t.OptAuthoDateTime BETWEEN '2015-07-27 00:00:00' AND '2015-09-01 00:00:00'
            AND     t.StgId = s.StgId
        );
```

The advantage of `EXISTS` is that it can use a semi-join, which essentially means rather than pulling back all the rows from the transaction table, it will stop the seek/scan as soon as it finds one matching record. This should leave you without duplicates so you can do the `SUM` directly:

```
SELECT  s.StgDescription, Amount = SUM(s.Amt)
FROM    tblstgmaster AS s
        INNER JOIN tblProjDocSt p on 
            t.TDocID = p.DocId
        INNER JOIN [PdasDb].[dbo].[tblIDmaster] AS f 
            ON p.ID = f.ID
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    [DinDb].[dbo].[tblTvlTransaction] AS t
            WHERE   t.OptAuthoDateTime BETWEEN '2015-07-27 00:00:00' AND '2015-09-01 00:00:00'
            AND     t.StgId = s.StgId
        )
GROUP BY s.StgDescription;
```

Comment: great suggestion but it's still a  guess, this table could also be producing repeats tblProjDocSt (project documentation? likely to be one-to-many)